# Adventure game for young children that don't speak English

Tags: game, children

I am trying to find an adventure game that I can play together with two young children (6-8 year old girls). I would like to introduce them to adventure games but since we live in a non-English speaking country they cannot understand English (they only speak Greek). Ideally I would like an adventure game that can be played without knowing English and that also has a childish - not-violent theme. I am thinking of something like a Myst clone aimed at younger children or Flight of the Amazon Queen without the English.
Though not essential, it would be nice if the game works with scummVM and can be purchased through gog or something similar.

Comment: When the time comes, I'll put a bounty on your question, because this needs more attention for sure. Although I live now in the US, I'm originally from Israel, so mother-tongue is Hebrew - another language without a lot of gaming content. An answer to your question would be a great thing to share with my nephews, nieces and grandkids back home.

Comment: You seem to speak english quite well though, so I imagine you could translate the story for your daughters on the fly. I played The Dig with my sons this way when they were too young to even read italian subtitles fast enough. It proved useful to introduce them to english language too.

Comment: Wish someone else would have answered this. really wanted to see some additional options around this.

Comment: @Lockszmith Thank you very much for the bounty. I will keep searching and I will add anything I find.

Comment: @shortmanikos did you find anything that I didn't list? if so, please respond with an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The universality of stories that are told without language is such a great asset.

Your question reminded me of [The Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Linea_(TV_series)) - a fantastic cartoon from the 80s that was completely wordless, yet a total pleasure to anyone of any age and any background.

I truly feel we need to chronicle this, please don't choose this as the selected answer - at least not quickly, let's hope others will add their answers.

However adventure games are very story oriented, and so, even in your example - Myst - without the told story (aka language) you are often left with a series of puzzles.
Some of my suggestions are exactly that, a series of puzzles, others are more platform like (remember Mario Bors.) Hopefully as the children these games are intend for will grow older, they might be able to shed the language barrier and enjoy the games again with the added layer of language-based-story-telling added to it.

#### From my personal experience:

- [Brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brothers:_A_Tale_of_Two_Sons) <sup>[gog](https://www.gog.com/game/brothers_a_tale_of_two_sons)</sup>
  I've played this on PS4, but it's available for PC.
- [Flower](https://thatgamecompany.com/flower) <sup>[gog](https://www.gog.com/game/flower)</sup> - no language at all
- [Journey](https://thatgamecompany.com/journey/) <sup>Not on gog</sup> - no language at all
- [Unravel](https://www.ea.com/games/unravel) <sup>Not on gog</sup>
- [The Swapper](https://facepalmgames.com/the-swapper/) <sup>[gog](https://www.gog.com/game/the_swapper)</sup>
- [Portal](https://store.steampowered.com/app/400/Portal/) and [Portal 2](https://store.steampowered.com/app/620/Portal_2/) <sup>not on gog, steam only</sup>, as well as [Bridge Constructor: Portal](https://headupgames.com/game/bridge-constructor-portal) <sup>[gog](https://www.gog.com/game/bridge_constructor_portal)</sup> - while language is key for the humor, the game is extremely fun without it.
- [Another World](http://www.anotherworld.fr/anotherworld_uk/) <sup>[gog](https://www.gog.com/game/another_world_20th_anniversary_edition)</sup>.
- [Monument Valley](https://www.monumentvalleygame.com/mv1) and its [sequel](https://www.monumentvalleygame.com/mv2)
  A series of puzzles, where the plot line isn't very important.
  I've played both on Android / Fire Tablet - and they are exquisite. But - they are not available for PC (unless you run an Android emulator like [LDPlayer](https://www.ldplayer.net/) or [NOX](https://www.bignox.com/)).

I also did a little search and found the following interesting - I have not tested any of these yet:

- [Samorost 3](https://amanita-design.net/games/samorost3.html) <sup>[gog](https://www.gog.com/game/samorost_3) [itch.io](https://amanitadesign.itch.io/samorost-3)</sup>, looks like [Samorost 1](https://amanita-design.net/games/samorost-1.html) is [free on gog](https://www.gog.com/game/samorost_1)
- [Oquonie](https://100r.co/site/oquonie.html) <sup>[itch.io](https://hundredrabbits.itch.io/oquonie)</sup>
- [Hiversaires](https://100r.co/site/hiversaires.html) <sup>[itch.io](https://hundredrabbits.itch.io/hiversaires)</sup>